# How can I stop or mute an Facebook video embedded via JavaScript SDK on my own page? (my page is in my own domain)

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am coding a very simple selector for facebook's videos to embed in my page (in my own domain) it is working.. but when I change the video the sound of the previous one does not stop. The selector works with the Facebook's Javascript SDK and the Js codes of each video, and selects them via CSS using jquery addClass and removeClass. to add / remove them the "display:none" CSS property.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fb player</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '{xxxxxxxxxxxx}',
xfbml      : true,
version    : 'v2.5'
});
// Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
var my_video_player;
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
if (msg.type === 'video') {
my_video_player = msg.instance;
}
});
};
(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<!-- Your embedded video player code -->
<div  
class="fb-video" 
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/videos/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/" 
data-width="500" 
data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
<button onClick="my_video_player.pause()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and this one is the code I've used before (before i've created an facebook's developer account and get an Id for my App) for hide / unhide the videos via jquery / CSS

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fb Live Player</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<style>
.outview{ display:none;}
#vid0ctn{ width:500px; height:30rem;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--SDK FB-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!--SDK FB END-->
<div id="vid0ctn">
<div>Video placeholder</div>
</div>
<div id="vid1ctn" class="outview">
<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/buzzfeedtasty/videos/1909246735994633/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/buzzfeedtasty/videos/1909246735994633/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/buzzfeedtasty/videos/1909246735994633/">6 Cheesecake Recipes</a><p>These 6 cheesecake recipes will have all your cheesecake cravings covered  !
FULL RECIPES: http://bzfd.it/2pIMiU9</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/buzzfeedtasty/">Tasty</a> on viernes, 21 de abril de 2017</blockquote></div>
</div>
<div id="vid2ctn" class="outview">
<div  class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/NowThisFuture/videos/1541708712536970/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/NowThisFuture/videos/1541708712536970/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/NowThisFuture/videos/1541708712536970/">Roads Made From Recycled Plastic</a><p>Roads made with recycled plastic are a win for drivers, local governments, and the earth</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/NowThisFuture/">NowThis Future</a> on viernes, 28 de abril de 2017</blockquote></div>
</div>
<button id="vidbtn1" class="button">xxxxx VIDEO</button><button id="vidbtn2" class="button">xxxxxx FB VIDEO</button>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#vidbtn1").click(function() {
$("#vid1ctn").removeClass("outview");
$("#vid0ctn").addClass("outview");
$("#vid2ctn").addClass("outview");
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#vidbtn2").click(function() {
$("#vid2ctn").removeClass("outview");
$("#vid0ctn").addClass("outview");
$("#vid1ctn").addClass("outview");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the whole idea on this is (once i get able to manipulate the video player )load several facebook videos in one div and manipulate them with buttons outside the player itself

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it is unclear how you set your selector, but perhaps you can make use of the [Player Controls API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api#control-reference) that the SDK provides. You can use the `pause()` method to  pause the video that is playing before starting the new one.